# Eloquent javascript chapter 4 Computing correlation

Tags: javascript

I’m currently going through book Eloquent JS and I can’t understand this code below:

```
function tableFor(event, journal) {
  let table = [0, 0, 0, 0];
  for (let i = 0; i < journal.length; i++) {
    let entry = journal[i], index = 0;
    if (entry.events.includes(event)) index += 1;
    if (entry.squirrel) index += 2;
    table[index] += 1;
  }
  return table;
}

console.log(tableFor("pizza", JOURNAL));
// → [76, 9, 4, 1]
```

---

You can look up JOURNAL here: https://eloquentjavascript.net/code/#4

And chapter here: https://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html - Computing correlation

Particularly I can’t understand this line

`let entry = journal[i], index = 0;`

I know that we reassign every object of the journal to entry, but what index=0 does? And every other index:

```
index += 2;
table[index] += 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

The function first initializes that `table` array with four zeros. Note also that the possible values for `index` on each iteration of that loop are:

- 0, if the entry does not include the "event", and does not have the "squirrel" flag set;
- 1, if the entry does include "event" but no squirrel;
- 2, if the entry does not include "event" but squirrel;
- 3, if the entry both includes "event" and is a squirrel

Those four values will act as indexes into the table. Each iteration of the loop adds one to one of the four table cells, so when the loop is finished the table contains counts of each of those different kinds of entries.

Oh, and at the top of the loop

```
     let entry = journal[i], index = 0;
```

that's just a declaration of `entry` and `index`.

Answer (score 1):

```
let entry = journal[i], index = 0
```

is shorthand for

```
let entry = journal[i];
let index = 0;
```

it works similarly for var, const and global declarations:

```
var entry = journal[i], index = 0
```

would translate to

```
var entry = journal[i];
var index = 0;
```

Comment: Oh God! I forgot that we can assign in one line variables. :) Thx man!

Comment: You don't see it that often because it's usually regarded as "bad practice" in my experience. Especially with eslint: `Expected variable declaration to be on a new line.eslint(one-var-declaration-per-line)`

Answer (score 1):

It is basically a bitmask:

If `index` is 0, the entry has no squirel and the event is not included.

If `index` is 1, the entry's events includes the event.

If `index` is 2, it has a squirel.

If `index` is 3 (2 + 1), it has a squirel and the event is included.

Now that index is used to increase one of the table's counters, the first value in the table will contain a count of all entries with no squirel and no event and so on

Answer (score 1):

1. let **table = [0, 0, 0, 0]**

This array's elements are used to track 4 situations:

**table[0]** - when a certain event does not occur (e.g. no pizza) and outcome is false (e.g squirrel transformation is false)

**table[1]** - when a certain event occurs (e.g. pizza) but outcome is false (e.g squirrel transformation is false)

**table[2]** - when a certain event does not occur (e.g. no pizza) but outcome is true (e.g squirrel transformation is true)

**table[3]** - when a certain event occurs (e.g. pizza) and outcome is true (e.g squirrel transformation is true)

2. **let entry = journal[i], index = 0**

   **journal[i]** basically selects the object (journal is an array of objects) at the i-th iteration through journal,  in the for-loop defined in **for (let i = 0; i < journal.length; i++)** and stores it in the variable **entry**.

**index = 0** is also a variable with default value of 0. it is used to set the default index of **table = [0, 0, 0, 0]** (as you will soon see)

3. when the **console.log(tableFor("pizza", JOURNAL))** is run, the for-loop is on the first iteration (i=0). it goes to journal[0], and sets entry = journal[0].

   - it runs **if (entry.events.includes(event))** i.e. if **events**
     (which is an item in the object at journal[0]-now referenced by entry) contains/includes event e.g. pizza. If it does, it increases index by 1 (**index += 1**)
   - It then goes to the next line **if (entry.squirrel)** and
     does the check i.e. if the second item in the object at journal[0]
     occurs e.g. if squirrel is true. if it is, it increases index by 2
     (**index += 2**).

**A.** For the sake of simplicity, lets assume only the first condition is true i.e. it only runs **index += 1** because when it ran **(entry.events.includes(event))**, it found the pizza event but when it ran **(entry.squirrel) index += 2;** squirrel was false, therefore index +=2 will be ignored. At this point, **table[index] = table[1]** **BECAUSE** index = 0 has been increased by 1 at **index += 1** as all other conditions have been found to be false. Then the table[1] += 1 is run and the table becomes [0, 1, 0, 0]. (Remember that you can change the elements of an array in this manner (select an index in the array and set it to a new value with the = operator))

In the case that the first condition was checked and no pizza event was found as well as squirrel=false, index = 0 remains, therefore table[index] = table[0]. Then the table[0] += 1 is run and the table becomes [1, 0, 0, 0]

**B.** Assuming **ONLY** **if (entry.squirrel) index += 2;** is true, and the previous line **if (entry.events.includes(event)) index += 1;** was such that index = 0 remains, index is increased from 0 to 2 because **index += 2**. At this point table[index] = table[2]. when table[2] += 1 is run and the table becomes [0, 0, 1, 0] because the table goes to index 2 and sets it to 1.

**C.** In the case that the two **if** conditions are true, index = 0 is increased by 1 at **if (entry.events.includes(event)) index += 1;**, and further by 2 at **if (entry.squirrel) index += 2;**. i.e. index = 0 +1 +2 = 3. At this point, index = 3 and table[index] = table[3]. Therefore, table[3] += 1 updates table to table[0, 0, 0, 1]

The loop (**for (let i = 0; i < journal.length; i++)**) goes on from **journal[0]** till **journal[length - 1]**, updating **table = [0,0,0,0]** from index to index, increasing the items at each table index one at a time due to **table[index] += 1**, as the conditions are checked, till the last object in the journal array has been checked and table has finished updating.

I hope I have helped you a little

Answer (score 0):

```js
I would like to clarify something to all of you who don't seem to know what math is going on behind the indices. 

There's a math going on here. In the book the author uses an array of [76, 9, 4, 1].
In this array, the position of 76 is at index 0, the position of 9 is 1, the position of 4 is 2, and the position of 1 is 3. 
When you convert 0 from decimal to binary you get 00 meaning both event did not occur.
When you convert 1 from decimal to binary you get 01 meaning no squirrel but there's pizza
When you convert 2 from decimal to binary you get 10 meaning there is squirrel and no pizza
When you convert 3 from decimal to binary you get 11 meaning there is squirrel and there is pizza.
76 gets position 0 corresponding to 00 meaning there was no squirrel and no pizza at the same time 76 times
9 gets  position 1 corresponding to 01 meaning there was no squirrel and there was pizza at the same time 9 times
4 gets  position 2 corresponding to 10 meaning there was squirrel and no pizza at the same time 4 times
1 gets position 3 corresponding to 11 meaning there was squirrel and there was pizza at the same time just 1 time
Now when you write your code, [0,0,0,0] follows the same logic.
```